# How to style my application in WPF using app.xaml

Tags: wpf, styles, app.xaml

I've successfully added a resource dictionary (containing my theme/collection of styles template resources) to my Window.Resources. This styles each of my windows appropriately. However, when I add the same line:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="BureauBlack.xaml" x:Key="BureauBlackKey"/>
```

To my App.xaml nothing changes.

Edit #1:

```
<Application x:Class="EventPlanner.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EventPlanner.ViewModels"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocatorKey"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BureauBlack.xaml" x:Key="BureauBlackKey"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I don't think i understand your problem, but you do know how resource lookup works, do you? Lets say you have a resource in the app.xaml and in your window, both named the same. If you now search for it in the window, the first occurence is taken, which is the resource in the window. [See](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx#staticdynamic) . Btw. Resource Dictionaries doesn't need a x:Key, it doesn't hurt but also does nothing.

Comment: If I don't add a key it gives me an error saying that everything inside a Resource Dictionary requires a Key value. I'll post my App.xaml (should've done that to start).

Comment: You don't add ResourceDictionaries like that. If you want to add a xaml to be used to search for resources, similar to an include, you add it to a [MergedDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the theme resource dictionary to the `MergedDictionaries` collection:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BureauBlack.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- other resources go here -->

        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocatorKey"/>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```